# TypeError: string.charCodeAt is not a function. How to encode object in node.js using express (restful api)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I use restful API with express & node.js and want to encode data to utf-8.

1. I install utf8 with `npm install utf8`
2. I set `const utf8 = require('utf8');`
3. I use `utf8.encode(string)` to object like that:

   ```
    pool.query(`SELECT Station, Ime FROM auto_q_stations;`, function (error, result2, fields) {


    if (error)
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Грешна заявка. Опитай отново !" })
      HQstationsAHS = result2;
      res.json({ HQstationsAHS })
    });
   ```

   });

I receive error like that:

```
TypeError: string.charCodeAt is not a function
```

**How to encode object in node.js using express (restful api) ?**

My problem is the following, when I execute a query in a database, all data in Bulgarian are OK.

When I execute the query in node.is & express environment I receive the data like that:

```
"������-��������"
```

Please help, I really don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: Are you sure result is a string?

Comment: This is the result: http://194.141.118.43:3002/HQstationsAHS

Comment: This input result needs to be a string `utf8.encode(result);` not an array or a object. You need to loop the array of objects for each "Ime" field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through your array and change every "Ime" field.
Something like

```
pool.query(`CALL Get_Discharge_Station('${dateNow}', ${daysBefore}, ${stNumber})`, function (error, result, fields) {
   if (error)
     return res.status(500).json({ error: "Грешна заявка. Опитай отново !" })

    HQstationsAHS = result2.map((item) => {
      item.Ime = utf8.encode(item.Ime);
      return item;
    });

   res.json({ HQstationsAHS })
 });
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Comment: I update my question little bit, because I had mistaken the function of this query this is the correct one, can you give me an exact example because I have a crawl error

Comment: Now works but � is still there ;((((